# XAdES - XL verification program?

Tags: xml, certificate, signature

Is there any XAdES-XL verification programs , or I need to manually create it for my signature ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a few options:

- Components

  - https://www.nsoftware.com/kb/articles/legacy/sbb/implementingxades.rst
- Projects

  - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1256991/The-AdES-Collection-CAdES-XAdES-PAdES-and-ASiC
  - https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/test/java/xades4j/verification/XadesVerifierImplTest.java
  - https://code.google.com/archive/p/eid-dss/
- Discussions

  - [Library to manage XAdES signatures in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193426/library-to-manage-xades-signatures-in-java)
- Online tools

  - https://account.ascertia.com/demos/xmlsignatureverificationstep1

I would be happy to fulfill the list with options other people leave in the comments.